# Disabled send otp via call from firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have an application that right now login by phone using firebase phone authentication. Everything works fine but my customer said that they receive OTP via call not via text message.

When I develop this feature I never receive any call, but right now it does.
So I don't know is there any option to setting for this - kind of way to receive OTP

Can we disable this to only use text message to receive OTP only